# GLIBC_2.27 not Found in Docker Container

Tags: linux, docker

I am now running a Docker container in my Linux machine. The dockerfile is as follows:

```
# 1. basic image
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.12.0-devel-py3

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en' LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"

# 2. apps
RUN apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
    software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make && \
    apt update \
    && apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        vim \
        ubuntu-make \
        && umake ide pycharm /root/.local/share/umake/ide/pycharm
```

Everything goes on well, but when I enter the Docker container using the following command:

```
sudo docker run --ipc=host --gpus all --net=host -it -d --rm -h docker -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw
-v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, -v /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
  --privileged
```

Then I try command such as `apt update`, I will receive the following messages:

```
apt: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0)
```

However, this will not happen if the command is invoked in the Docker image file `Dockerfile`. For example, at the end of the `Dockerfile`, if I invoke
`RUN apt update && apt install -y firefox`, no errors appear.

I cannot understand why only in the Docker container is `GLIBC_2.27` link problem identified.

Comment: Can you add your Dockerfile to your post so we can reproduce your error, please?

Comment: `when I enter the Docker container` How do you do it? Please post the command line.

Comment: @HansKilian The Dockerfile is provided. Thanks

Comment: @KamilCuk The command is provided. Thanks.

Comment: Does the same happen with `docker run tensorflow/tensorflow:1.12.0-devel-py3`? If not - remove stuff from your `docker run` or from `Dockerfile` until you find out the culprit option. `apt update && apt install` The issue could be a partial update.

Comment: @KamilCuk Good idea, and I use your method and found the problem. I will write down in the answer section. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer thanks to the help of @KamilCuk.

The reason why I got this error is because my host machine is Ubuntu 18.04 and my guest machine (Container) is Ubuntu 16.04.

This is no problem, but when I enter the Container, I share the two folders between host machine and guest machine:

- `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`
- `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`

As a result, the guest system tries to use libraries in the host machine, which is wrong. I forgot the reason why I decide to share host machine's libraries with the guest machine. Anyway, if I disable it, everything goes on well.